# Div images in marquee tag show on two rows instead of one

Tags: php, html

I am using a marquee tag to show dynamically div image in only one row, but it show the first 4 divs in one row and the 5th div show in the next row. How can I solve this.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="panel panel-body " style="background-color:rgba(212,209,209,1.00) ; width:auto; height:380px;   box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px  rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); margin-top:30px;">

   <marquee  direction="left" behavior="scroll"  scrollamount="10"  onMouseOver="stop()"  onMouseOut="start()" >

  <?php


    $products= features(); 

     if (!empty($products))  
        foreach($products as $value){
     ?>



        <div class="col-md-3  grid-product-in" >

        <div class=" product-grid"> 
            <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $value\["productID"\] ?>&ids=<?php echo $value\["subcategoryID"\] ?>"><img width="234px" height="214px" src="admin/html/uploads/<?php echo $value\["image"\] ?>" alt=""></a>      
            <div class="shoe-in">
                <h6><a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $value\["productID"\] ?>&ids=<?php echo $value\["subcategoryID"\] ?>"><?php echo $value\["productname"\] ?> </a></h6>
                <label>$<?php echo $value\["price"\] ?></label>
                <a href="product.php" class="store"><?php echo $value\["name"\] ?></a>
            </div>


        </div>  
        </div>


        <?php } ?>

        </marquee>

</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

it is now showing 4 items in a row because you are using col-md-3

its a bootstrap class.
if you want to show all in a single row. try to give it a spesific width. ie:

```
<div style="width:200px;" class="grid-product-in">
```

or simply change it to col-md-12 class

```
<div class="col-md-12 grid-product-in">
```